# Estimate the homogeneous components of a polynomial against its maximum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, inequalities

Let $P\equiv P(x) := \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} c_\alpha\cdot x^\alpha$ be a real polynomial in $d$ variables of (total) degree $m$, where $d, m \in\mathbb{N}$ are fixed.

(I.e., the above sum ranges over all multiindices $\alpha=(i_1, \ldots, i_d)\in\mathbb{N}_0^{\times d}$ of length $|\alpha|\equiv i_1+\ldots + i_d$ less than $m$.)

Denote by $P_k = \sum_{|\alpha|=m}c_\alpha\cdot x^\alpha$, $ 0\leq k\leq m$, the $k$-th homogeneous component of $P$.

I was wondering the following: Given a compact subset $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, is it possible to for $\varphi_K(P):=\max_{0\leq k\leq m}\|P_k\|_{\infty; K}$ (or indeed for any $\ell_p$-norm of $(\|P_k\|_{\infty;K})_{k\geq 0}$ with $1\leq p \leq \infty$) find a constant $\kappa=\kappa(d,K)$ such that

$$\tag{1} \varphi_K(P) \ \leq \ \kappa\cdot \|P\|_{\infty; K} \qquad \text{ for each } \ P \ \text{ as above} \ ?$$

(Here, $\|f\|_{\infty;K}:=\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|$ is the uniform norm over $K$.) Any references are welcome.

Comment: It looks like in several places you write $m$ where you mean to write $k$. As written the definition of $P_k$ does not depend on $k$. It would also be nice if instead of $||(P_m)||_{\infty;K}$ you just wrote $||(P)||_{\infty;k}$, since the former makes it look like it just depends on the $m$-th homogeneous component.

Comment: @Vik78 You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I edited accordingly. As for your comment re $(P_k)$, I wrote it that way to indicate that the norms in question refer to (the norms of the components of) the degree-based gradation $(P_k)$ of $P$.

Comment: Now you have changed its definition to read $||(P_k)||_{\infty;K}$ with $k$ as a subscript— but you are maximizing over $0 \le k \le m$ so it does not depend on $k$. Personally I find it confusing (and would just replace the entire symbol $||(\cdot)||$ with a function $f(P, K)$, since as written it looks very similar to the norm $||\cdot||$).

Comment: Do you want to have the constant $\kappa$ independent of the degree of the polynomial? This looks very unlikely.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Yes, $\kappa$ should be independent of the degrees of $P$ and $P_k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $d=1$, $K=[0,1]$, and, for $x\in K$,
$$P(x):=T_n(x):=n\sum_{0\le k\le n/2}\frac{(-1)^k}{n-k}\binom{n-k}k2^{n-2k-1}x^{n-2k}
=\cos(n\arccos x),$$
the $n$th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions).

Then $\|P\|_{\infty;K}\le1$, whereas (say) for $k=0$ we have $\|P_k\|_{\infty;K}=2^{n-1}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.